# Package installed executable doesn't load ConfigurationManager.AppSettings from .config file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-installer

I have an App.config XML file in my application project that I use to provide customizable options to the user.

I have an install project that installs the application project output and the configuration file to the program files folder.

If I launch the application from within Visual Studio, the configuration is loaded from file correctly.

The config settings don't get loaded when I launch the installed executable, but if I copy the executable from the application project binary output directory over the installed executable, it works.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I was building a DEBUG target and installer, whereas when I changed it to RELEASE, the installed application loaded the configuration correctly.  Apparently it is an issue with installing a debug version of an executable.  I have a fix/workaround (do not install a debug version of my application), but it would be interesting to know why it didn't work.